# How to adress variable Columns of SQL query with TWIG

Tags: php, sql, symfony, twig

I am trying to address a specific column of a SQL query depending on the value of another row from the query.

The result I am getting from the SQL query is something like this:

```
Number | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 
1      |      3 |      5 |     4
3      |      5 |      2 |     6
2      |      1 |      3 |     2
```

For each row, I want to get the Value of the Column by the Index of the Number. 
So for example in the first row, I want to get the Value of 'Value1', which is 3.
In the second row, I want to get the Value of 'Value3', which is 6, and so on.

Then I am iterating through the list with a TWIG for loop and can access the 'Number' parameter like this:

```
{% for key in examplelist|keys %}
   {% set number = examplelist[key].number %}
{% endfor %}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot address the 'Value'-columns using that number.

I have tried things like:

```
{{examplelist[key].Value . number }}
```

or

```
{{examplelist[key].Value + number }}
```

or

```
{{examplelist[key].Value ~ number }}
```

but none of these work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

The data gets returned as an object of the type stdClass, not as an array. Therefore you can't access it like an array and it has to be converted using

```
$Examplelist = json_decode($Examplelist, true);
return $Examplelist;
```

in the php part.

Afterwards, it can be adressed by using

```
{% set value  = examplelist[key]["Value"~number] %}
```

Thank you for the Help anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick

```
{% for key in examplelist|keys %}
   {% set number = examplelist[key].number %}
   {% set value  = examplelist[key]["Value"~number] %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: "somehow does not work" doesn't give much information to work with :) - this solution works with similar simple array data as illustrated in your question (I tested this with twig 2.6). So what do you get as error from the above? or from dumping the "value" value from above? Or what does it exactly mean that it somehow doesn't work? And can you dump the whole "examplelist" variable as well to see in what format you have the data there.